# Pass animation function as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm writing a simple function to animate a div (in this example called 'helpBox'). This div will fade in and slide down when it is executed.

However, I'd like to be able to pass in the type of animation I'd like to do alongside the fade. I'm fading in via manipulating the opactity attribute but I'm sliding down via use of slideDown(). The thing is, I'd like to be able to specifiy a particular animation to do alongside the fade (i.e. maybe a slideUp() to hide the help box again).

```
showHelp: function (helpBox, myAnimation) {
        if (!helpBox.is(':visible')) {
            helpBox.css('opacity', 0)
               .slideDown('slow') //have this function as the parameter (i.e. myAnimation)
               .animate
               (
                    { opacity: 1 },
                    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
               );
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'd like to replace the hard-coded .slideDown() with a function passed in (myAnimation). I have no idea how to call this though:

```
showHelp($('#myHelpBox'), function() { /*pass the animation in somehow*/ });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the parameter as a string(function name) and try this.

```
showHelp: function (helpBox, myAnimation) {
        if (!helpBox.is(':visible')) {
            helpBox.css('opacity', 0)[myAnimation]('slow')
               .animate
               (
                    { opacity: 1 },
                    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
               );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - although how do I actually pass in the (myAnimation) parameter when calling the showHelp() function? I.e. showHelp($('#myDiv, 'what goes here?');

Comment: If you want to call `slideDown` then try this `showHelp($('#myDiv, 'slideDown');`